# SwiftUI: Transition insertion does not work inside NavigationView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11, navigationview

When some view inside a NavigationView has a **transition** specified, only the **removal** works, the insertion one won't work.

```
NavigationView {
  VStack {
    if on {
      Text("a").transition(.slide)
    }
    Button("Show") { withAnimation { self.on.toggle() } }
  }
}
```

If you remove the `NavigationView`, then the text will properly slide when appearing.

Does anyone know how to work around it?

Comment: I tried and the sliding in and out works well with navigation or without it, please try Xcode 11.2 Beta 2

Comment: I found the same problem when using transitions in live preview in the canvas. Both insertion and removal work fine on the simulator / device